# Functor whose essential image is a cosieve?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sieve-theory

### Definitions

An object $d \in Obj(\mathcal D)$ is in the essential image of $F$ if there exists some $c \in Obj(\mathcal C)$ such that $d \cong F c$.

A [sieve in $\mathcal D$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sieve) is a full subcategory of $\mathcal D$ such that if $y$ is in the sieve and there is a morphism $\varphi : x \to y$, then $x$ is in the sieve.
Since sieves are required to be full, they can be regarded as subsets of $Obj(\mathcal{D})$.

A cosieve is the dual: if $x$ is in the cosieve and there is a morphism $\varphi : x \to y$, then $y$ is in the cosieve.

### Question

Is there a word for a functor $F : \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ satisfying the following three equivalent conditions:

- the objects in the essential image of $F$ constitute a cosieve in $\mathcal D$,
- the objects *outside* the essential image of $F$ constitute a sieve in $\mathcal D$,
- if there is a morphism $Fc \to d$, then $d$ is in the essential image of $F$.

Of course a word for the dual is also fine.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain the meaning of "constitute a cosieve" here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- A [discrete opfibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+fibration) $F : \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ has the property that every morphism $Fc \to d'$ is the image of a *unique* morphism $c \to c'$ *on the nose* (we need $Fc' = d'$).
- A [Grothendieck opfibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration) $F : \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ has the property that every morphism $Fc \to d'$ is the image of a *universal* ("cartesian") morphism $c \to c'$ *on the nose* (we need $Fc' = d'$).

  Thus, every discrete opfibration is a Grothendieck opfibration.

  If the opfibration is [cloven](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cleavage), meaning that a choice of cartesian morphisms has been made, then for every morphism $\varphi : d \to d'$ in $\mathcal D$, we get a functor $E^{-1}(\varphi) : E^{-1}(d) \to E^{-1}(d')$. Universality of the lifting of the arrow is what makes $E^{-1}$ a pseudofunctor.
- A [Street/weak opfibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration#StreetFibration) $F : \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ has the property that every morphism $Fc \to d$ is the image of a *universal* morphism $c \to c'$ *up to isomorphism* (we need $Fc' \cong d'$).

  Thus, every Grothendieck opfibration is a Street opfibration.
- A functor $F : \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ as described in the question, has the property that every morphism $Fc \to d$ is the image of *some* morphism $c \to c'$ *up to isomorphism* (we need $Fc' \cong d'$). Lacking universality, even if this were cloven (in the sense that a choice of liftings of morphisms to $\mathcal C$ has been made), we cannot expect $E^{-1}$ to satisfy the functor laws up to isomorphism.

  **Edit:** The question did not require the *morphism* to be in the image of $F$. Of course this will be automatic if $F$ is full.

So I guess a reasonable name (when morphisms are also lifted) would be **weak ad hoc opfibration**:

- Weak because it lifts arrows *up to isomorphism*,
- Ad hoc because we can choose liftings for arrows in an ad hoc manner, not caring about the bigger picture, since we need not satisfy pseudofunctoriality.

Comment: Since the question did not require the *morphism* to be in the image of $F$, we could go for **weak objectwise opfibration**, but does this still warrant using fibration terminology?